# Dimension of Proper Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm trying to prove the following, but I'm not sure if my logic is sound:

> Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. Prove that $\dim U \leq \dim V$.

My proof is as follows:

Suppose that $\dim V = n$ and $\dim U = n+1$

Thus the basis of $U$ has $n+1$ vectors. Since the vectors in a basis span the vector space, there exists a vector $\vec{v}$ in $U$ that can be written as such:

$\vec{v} = a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{n}u_{n}+a_{n+1}u_{n+1}$

Since $U$ is a subspace of $V$, $\vec{v}$ is also in $V$. Thus,$\vec{v}$ can be written out as the following:

$\vec{v} = a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_{n}v_{n}$

Therefore,
$\vec{v} = a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_{n}u_{n}+a_{n+1}u_{n+1} = a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_{n}v_{n}$

This is a contradiction as the additional vector in the basis of $U$ would have to be a linear combination of vectors in the basis of $V$ for the equality to hold. If the additional vector is linearly dependent, then it cannot be in the basis. Thus, $\dim U \leq \dim V$. QED

---

I'm not sure if I adequately expressed my logic. I'm pretty sure having a subspace with a basis larger than its superspace would not work because of linear dependence, but I don't know if I invoked it correctly.

Yes, this is a homework question for a linear algebra class, so I am not looking for an outright answer, just guidance should my proof be flawed (or confirmation that its correct).

Comment: How do you know that $a_{n+1}\neq 0$?

Comment: I think a direct proof is easier. If $u_1,...,u_n$ form a basis for $U$, then they are linearly independent in $V$, hence $\dim V \ge n = \dim U$.

Comment: @MichaelM. Should I specify that there must exist a vector in $U$ where $a_{n+1} \neq 0$? Or is my whole line of reasoning faulty?

Comment: @copper.hat That might be a better way to go (and probably what I'll end up submitting), but out of sheer curiosity I'll keep the question open to see if I can learn to solve the problem this way.

Comment: @user3288091 - When you say that $a_{n+1}u_{n+1}$ being in the linear span of $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ yields a contradiction, do you mean to prove that $u_{n+1}$ is in the linear span of $(u_1,\dots,u_n)$ instead? The first case doesn't prove that the u's are linearly dependent.

Comment: Well, it is a little awkward. You can express each $u_i = \sum_j [A]_{ji} v_j$, where $A$ is a $n \times (n+1)$ matrix. If a point has coordinates $\beta$ in the basis $u_k$ then the coordinates in the basis $v_k$ are $A\beta$. Because of the dimensions, there must be some $\beta \neq 0$ such that $A \beta = 0$. Then $\sum_k [\beta]_k u_k = 0$, a contradiction.